# Docker HTTPS access - ONLYOFFICE3

Tags: ssl, https, docker, environment-variables

I'm following the ONLYOFFICE Docker documentation
([GITHUB ONLYOFFICE docker HTTPS access](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/Docker-DocumentServer)) to get ONLYOFFICE
documentserver and communityserver running with `HTTPS`.

What I've tried:

1.

I've created the cert files (`.crt`, `.key`, `.pem`) like mentioned in the documentation. After that I created a file named `env.list` in my home dir `/home/jw/data/` with the following content:

```
SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH=/opt/onlyoffice/Data/certs/onlyoffice.crt
SSL_KEY_PATH=/opt/onlyoffice/Data/certs/onlyoffice.key
SSL_DHPARAM_PATH=/opt/onlyoffice/Data/certs/dhparam.pem
SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT=true
```

2.

After that I added the directory `/home/jw/data/` to my `$PATH` environment
variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/jw/data/; export PATH
```

3.

On the same shell I started the docker container like this:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d --name onlyoffice-document-server -p 443:443 -v /opt/onlyoffice/Data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data --env-file /home/jw/data/env.list onlyoffice/documentserver
```

4.

The documentserver is running fine. After that I've started the
communityserver with:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d --link onlyoffice-document-server:document_server --env-file /home/jw/data/env.list onlyoffice/communityserver
```

5.

With the command `docker ps -a` I see booth docker containers running fine:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
4f573111f2e5        onlyoffice/communityserver   "/bin/sh -c 'bash -C "   29 seconds ago      Up 28 seconds       80/tcp, 443/tcp, 5222/tcp      lonely_mcnulty
23543300fa51        onlyoffice/documentserver    "/bin/sh -c 'bash -C "   42 seconds ago      Up 41 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   onlyoffice-document-server
```

But when I'm trying to access `https://localhost` there is an error "Secure
Connection Failed" in Firefox.

Did I miss something?

Comment: what shows `docker port 4f5` and `docker port 235`, the doc is https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/

Comment: `% docker port onlyoffice-community-server 443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:443 80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay got it:

I've changed the environment variables in `env.list` to:

```
SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH=/var/www/onlyoffice/Data/certs/onlyoffice.crt
SSL_KEY_PATH=/var/www/onlyoffice/Data/certs/onlyoffice.key
SSL_DHPARAM_PATH=/var/www/onlyoffice/Data/certs/dhparam.pem
```

After that used the following command to run ONLY the documentserver:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d --name onlyoffice-document-server -p 443:443 -v /opt/onlyoffice/Data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data --env-file /home/jw/data/env.list onlyoffice/documentserver
```

The ONLYOFFICE OnlineEditor API is now available over HTTPS:

https://localhost/OfficeWeb/apps/api/documents/api.js

If you want to use CommunityServer with HTTPS just change the run command above to:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d --name onlyoffice-community-server -p 443:443 -v /opt/onlyoffice/Data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data --env-file /home/<username>/env.list onlyoffice/communityserver
```

Thank you anyway!